# How I can place list of IDs

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that creates a channel and a category, then writes the IDs of categories and channels to file `categorylist.json` (in which the IDs of categories created by the bot are written) and `channellist.json` (in which the IDs of channels created by the bot are written). After that, when a user joins the created channel with the bot, the bot clones and transfers the user to the new channel. When a user leaves a new channel, it is deleted because the bot deletes all GUILD channels where the number of connected users is zero.

I need to make the bot delete all channels equal to zero from the list `categorylist.json`, that is, created categories themselves. I attached my bot's code at the bottom. [js file](http://hastebin.com/zejisajuci.js)

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I need to put a file with a large number of IDs categories instead of `guild`.
I dont know how make it

```
    if (newState && newState.channelID) {
        ChannelJoin(newState.member, newState.guild.channels.resolve(newState.channelID));
    }
```

Edited:

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
    if (oldState && newState) {
        if (oldState.channelID === newState.channelID) {
            return;
        }
    }
    CreatorCategory = ReadCreatorCategory();
    if (oldState && oldState.channelID) {
        ChannelLeave(oldState.member, oldState.guild.channels.resolve(oldState.channelID));
    }
    if (newState && newState.channelID) {
        ChannelJoin(newState.member, newState.guild.channels.resolve(newState.channelID));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide more information and explain what you are trying to do? Right now the question isn't very clear.

Comment: Hey. I need to replace the ```guild``` with a list of categories, so that the bot does not view the entire server, but only a specific category. and the list of categories is in the file categorylist.json

Comment: What `guild` are you referring to? The only `guild` in your code snippet is in `newState.guild`, and we don't know what `newState` is meant to be. Could you please edit your question to provide more context? See [ask].

Comment: Do provide more context for what your are trying to achieve, a code snippet alone is not enough. Are you trying to iterate through a guild's categories based on some json data's array of category IDs, to do something in the limited, matching categories?

Comment: My bot creates a channel and a category, then writes the IDs of categories and channels to file categorylist.json (in which the IDs of categories created by the bot are written) and channellist.json (in which the IDs of channels created by the bot are written). After that, when the user joins the created channel with the bot, the bot clones and transfers the user to the new channel. When a user leaves a new channel, it is deleted because: The bot has a function that deletes all GUILD channels where the number of connected users is zero.

Comment: I need to make the bot delete all channels equal to zero from the list categorylist.json, that is, created categories themselves. I attached my bot's code at the bottom.
https://hastebin.com/zejisajuci.js

Comment: Hi! I've added your comment details to the question, but it seems like you're asking two things - one is about putting IDs in a file, one is removing lines from `categorylist.json`. Are you able to take another go at explaining the question so that no-one misunderstands what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to delete all the category channels whose IDs are in `categorylist.json` that do not have any child channels. You need to do 4 things:

1. Read the contents of `categorylist.json`
2. Fetch the channel categories from the IDs in step 1
3. Find the categories from step 2 that have 0 child channels
4. Delete the channels from step 3

```js
// This is object destructuring: it’s the same as
// const readFile = require('fs').promises.readFile
const {readFile} = require('fs').promises


// Step 1
readFile('categorylist.json', 'utf8')
  .then(text => {
    const ids = JSON.parse(text)

    // Step 2: fetch categories
    return Promise.all(ids.map(id => client.channels.fetch(id)))
  })
  .then(categories => {
    // Step 3: find categories
    // The following is also destructuring: a => a.b is the same as ({b}) => b
    const emptyCategories = categories.filter(({children}) => !children.size)

    // Step 4: Delete channels
    return Promise.all(emptyCategories.map(channel => channel.delete()))
  })
  .catch(error => {
    throw error
  })
```

The same code with ES2017 `async`/`await`:

```js
async function deleteEmptyCategories() {
  try {
    // Step 1
    const text = await readFile('categorylist.json', 'utf8')
    const ids = JSON.parse(text)

    // Step 2
    const categories = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => client.channels.fetch(id)))

    // Step 3
    const categoriesWithNoChildren = categories.filter(({children}) => !children.size)

    // Step 4
    await Promise.all(categoriesWithNoChildren.map(channel => channel.delete()))
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```